# Does mc (Midnight Commander) have favourites for directories?

Tags: mc

If I am in remote directory on different server via ssh I want to do to directory like `/var/lib/edumate/backup` without typing the whole path. Is there any way to do that in mc?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In MC favourites or bookmarks are stored in the hotlist directory.

> **Hotlist**
>
> The Directory hotlist command shows the labels of the directories in the directory hotlist. The Midnight Commander will change to the directory corresponding to the selected label. From the hotlist dialog, you can remove already created label/directory pairs and add new ones. To add new directories quickly, you can use the Add to hotlist command (<kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>,<kbd>h</kbd>), which adds the current directory into the directory hotlist, asking just for the label for the directory.
>
> This makes cd to often used directories faster. You may consider using the CDPATH variable as described in internal cd command description. [1]

You can also use the hotlist to store frequently accessed ftp sites: if you access a site regularly, add it to your directory hotlist for faster access. Go to Command menu - Directory Hotlist - add by either typing it in, or if you are connected in a panel already, simply Add Current. Access the list with <kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>.[2]

1. http://linux.die.net/man/1/mc
2. http://www.trembath.co.za/mctutorial.html

Comment: great answer. Created new one though :-) http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14641/can-i-cd-or-use-hot-directory-in-shell-link-in-mc

Comment: Somehow CDPATH stopped working for me while inside `mc` and this drives me crazy. I tried switching shell before starting mc, or displaying value of CDPATH from mc and all seems ok but it fails to change directory.

Comment: where is this 'Directory hotlist' ? best howTo to to edit this 'Directory hotlist' ?

Answer (score 0):

My Workaround:

`$ mc ~/DocumentsBla/ ~/DokumenteFasel/`

then save (or open it like so later) it as SH-Script:

`~/MCTabs/MyFavorite1.sh`

this Workarounds is fast in reading favorites, but slow in creating favorites.