# can I cd or use hot directory in shell link in mc?

Tags: mc

can I use **hot directory** or **cd** inside shell link in mc?

I access about 40 linux boxes via shell link that have the same dir /var/lib/edumate/backup

how can I access this directory

- without typying the whole path and
- without creating extra hot directory entry for every single box?

Comment: Although this is the exact opposite of your second requirement, I would write a short script to append a new entry for the directory to `~/.mc/hotlist` on all of your boxes.  This would not take too long and would work unless you are opposed to adding a new entry for some other reason.